# How to create and active Left sidebar on Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I can't create left sidebar.

I created a file into child theme folder: sidebar-left.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly ?>
  <aside class="sidebar">            
  <!-- SIDEBAR WIDGET AREA -->
    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'lhsidebar' ) ) : ?>
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'lhsidebar' ); ?>
      <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php esc_html_e('No widgets added', 'rehub-theme'); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>        
   </aside>
```

Then, I have added this code into child theme's **function.php**:

```
// Left SideBar
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Left Sidebar', 'rehub' ),
        'id'            => 'lhsidebar',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', 'rehub' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

But where should I put the `get_sidebar('sidebar-left')`?

Comment: What do you expect will call the file `sidebar-left.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the sidebar inside any template of your child theme either by using the `get_sidebar()` function:

```
<?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
```

**Note:** the name of the file without `sidebar-` part at the begin of the name as mentionned in the [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/).

Either by using the `get_template_part()` function if your template file is not in the same directory as the sidebar file.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'sidebar-templates/sidebar', 'left' ); ?>
```

**Note:** here the full name of the sidebar is mentionned in the function, as well as its path from the root of the child-theme, cf [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/).